# Calling a class defined from another module

Tags: 8

I am calling the method defined in a class implemented from another module using the following code.

```
use Drupal\module_name\MyClassName;

$instance = Drupal\module_name\MyClassName::getinstance($host, $user, $pass);
```

My code doesn't work, as I get an error about a class not found. What am I doing wrong?

The class is contained in module/src/controiller/controller_name.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your comment, you say the class is inside module/src/controiller/controller_name.php, but you refer to the class as `Drupal\module_name\MyClassName`. That is wrong.
Assuming module_name is the directory containing your module (and the short name of the module itself), and that module_name/src/Controller/controller_name.php is the file containing the class definition, you need to use the following code.

```
use \Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyClassName;

$instance = MyClassName::getinstance($host, $user, $pass);
```

That is evident in any file referring a class, for example [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.routing.yml/8.2.x).

```
user.logout:
  path: '/user/logout'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::logout'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

As you notice, the class is referenced as `\Drupal\user\Controller\UserController`, not `\Drupal\user\UserController`.

Also, the filename is generally the name of the class plus the php extension, so in your case the file name should be module_name/src/Controller/MyClassName.php, not module_name/src/Controller/controller_name.php.

As side note, if you are calling a static method for a controller class, you probably need to do something more than just invoking it. Normally, controllers get also the dependency injection container; without that, they would not work. See for example [`UserController::create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Controller%21UserController.php/function/UserController%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x).

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
  return new static(
  $container->get('date.formatter'), 
  $container->get('entity.manager')->getStorage('user'), 
  $container->get('user.data')
  );
}
```

If you call controller a class that is not a controller class as Drupal defines that, then your code could work; differently, if you are calling a Drupal controller class, resolved the error about a class not found, you will get more errors to fix.

Comment: Yes  i modified like that , now error log says  **Class 'Drupal\\module_name\\ControllerName\\ClassName'**  not found and am using it like on top of the file as **use \Drupal\module_name\ControllerName\ClassName;** and calling it like  **$instance = ClassName::getinstance($host, $user, $pass);**

Comment: You are using ControllerName, not Controller. If the class is contained in the module_name/src/Controller directory, the error message is correct. Also, you don't use \\ as separator, but \; so, it is `class Drupal\module_name\Controller\ClassName`.

Comment: Thanks ! it resolved my problem :) , and thats about error log ,no need to worry

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your class is under my_module\src, in a file called MyClassname.php, then refer to it via its fully qualified namespace:

```
$instance = Drupal\my_module\MyClassname::getinstance($host, $user, $password);
```

Or alias it:

```
// Top of file
use Drupal\my_module\MyClassname;

// Later on
$instance = MyClassname::getinstance($host, $user, $password);
```

Comment: many thanks . i was not included the module though :( .

Comment: still class not found error coming , i created the module/src/controiller/controller_name.php structure and called the constructor . am using  **class MyClassName extends ControllerBase** instead of a **class MyClassName** structure

Comment: This isn't Drupal-specific stuff, it's just PHP - you need to learn about Namespaces, autoloading, and how those two things fit together. As far as Drupal knowledge goes, just know that everything in "mymodule\src\*" is addressable as `Drupal\mymodule\*`. So your controller in this case is at `Drupal\mymodule\controller\MyClassName`. Once you understand namespacing, everything else will make perfect sense.

Comment: Yes i have used the name space as **use Drupal\module_name\MyClassName;** and called it via **Drupal\module_name\MyClassName::getinstance($host, $user, $pass);**

Comment: Assuming you've followed all the other advice in this answer/comments, that will work fine. Though you don't need to fully qualify the class every time if it's `use`d

Comment: as another answer mentions, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200599/1082 your class needs to implement the static method `getInstance` as well, unless your class `extends` a class which does implement this to provide an instance of your class. If you want to implement your own creation function, that other example also mentions `new static`, which will create an object of your class, rather than its parent, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849805/should-i-use-new-self-or-new-static explains.